# creating a list of type vectors of fixed size

Tags: c++, list, c++17, stdvector

i want a list of type vector with vector size=3

i tried writing

`typedef vector<int> vec; list<vec(3)> q;`

but it gave me this error

```
sol.cpp:22:12: error: temporary of non-literal type ‘vec’ {aka ‘std::vector<int>’} in a constant expression
   22 |       list<vec(3)> q;
      |            ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/vector:67,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/functional:62,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/pstl/glue_algorithm_defs.h:13,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/algorithm:74,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11/bits/stdc++.h:65,
                 from sol.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_vector.h:389:11: note: ‘std::vector<int>’ is not literal because:
  389 |     class vector : protected _Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>
      |           ^~~~~~
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "vector of fixed size". Vector can always change size. You can use `std::array<int, 3>` if you want constant size.

Comment: If you're using short arrays, you can also use `std::tuple`.

Comment: `std::list` expects a **type** as its first template parameter.  `vec(3)` is not a type.  It is an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually want a list of `std::vector<int>` with size 3, you just need to create a list of `std::vector<int>` and then construct each vector with size 3. For example, the following line creates a list of 4 vectors each of which has size 3:

```cpp
std::list<std::vector<int>> ls(4, std::vector<int>(3));
```

However, there is nothing to prevent you from changing the size of these vectors or adding more vectors to the list with a size other than 3. If you want a compile-time guarantee that every object in this list should have size 3, then you should use `std::array` instead of `std::vector`. For example, the following line creates an empty list of arrays of size 3:

```cpp
std::list<std::array<int, 3>> ls;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a `std::vector` of fixed size.

If you must limit the number of entries to 3, then use a `std::array<int, 3>`:

```
#include <array>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

using Array3 = std::array<int, 3>;
using ListArray3 = std::list<Array3>;

int main()
{
   ListArray3 l3 = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
   std::cout << "The number of arrays in the list are: " << l3.size() << "\n";
   for (auto& a : l3)
   {
      for (auto i : a)
        std::cout << i << " ";
      std::cout << "\n";        
   }
}
```

Output:

```
The number of arrays in the list are: 2
1 2 3 
4 5 6
```

Comment: To answer the OP's question, there is a way to make a std::vector of fixed size. `const std::vector<int> v(3);` for instance. It's size is fixed. You can't, however, put these in a list or vector etc. because allocator<const T> is not allowed. Oh, and elements can be modified: `const_cast<int&>(v[0]) = 42;`  That said, yeah, just use `std::array` and, unlike const vectors,  they can be put in containers.